# Headless bittorrent client to support magnet links

Tags: linux, command-line, bittorrent

I've installed `bittorrent` package via Apt on GNU/Linux, but `btdownloadheadless` command doesn't support magnet links.

Is there any other bittorrent terminal based client which works with magnet links (installation via `apt-get` is preferable)? Especially the one which would work similar to Wget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) has a built in CLI, GUI and web-interface.
- [Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com/) has also a built in CLI and GUI.
- since in [MLDonkey](http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) the core and GUIs are completely separated, all features will work via CLI.
- if you just want a CLI have a look at [rTorrent](https://rakshasa.github.io/rtorrent/) although with [ruTorrent](https://github.com/Novik/ruTorrent) there is also a third-party web-interface.
- if you want a similar CLI to wget maybe have a look at [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/), but it has a CLI only.

---

for sure all of them are capable of magnet-links...
since you said, you use *apt on GNU/Linux*, i assume you are using Debian or a debian-based distribution, so all of them are in the debian repositories (except ruTorrent).